# How to fix title bar using phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap to develop an android app and I would like to fix a title bar to prevent scrolling. It's seem like a facebook title bar on the top of facebook app.

How should I do it?

Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by making use of fixed toolbars in jquery mobile.How to acheive this is well documented in the jquery mobile docs page.Here is the link to it - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Please note that proper "fixed" toolbar support in JQM is limited to the following browsers

```
Browser support for fixed toolbars

iOS5 – iPhone and iPad
Android 2.2 and 2.3
Android 3.x tablets (Honeycomb)
Android 4.x (ICS)
Chrome for Android (beta)
BB Playbook 1-2
BB7
Nook Color/Tablet
Kindle Fire
Kindle 3
All modern desktop browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc.)
```

as mentioned in the JQM official blog - http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use JQM's fixed toolbar for that.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
</div>
```

Here is a simple jqm page illustrating that. http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/y7XAW/1/